# JSON response format is not correct (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I have a problem with a JSON response when I call Youtube api with angularJS :

Code:

```js
      sc.factory('videoApi', ['$resource', function($resource) {
          return $resource( 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', 
             {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
             { 
              get: { 
                method: 'GET', 
                params: { 
                  order: 'date',
                  part: 'snippet',
                  channelId: 'UCY8ZYY7YSQ80JW1Ijo2BJvA',
                  type: 'video',
                  key: '*** my key ***' },
                isArray : false,
              } 
            } );
        }]); 



      sc.controller('scontroller', ['$scope','videoApi', function ($scope,videoApi) {
          videoApi.get().$promise.then(function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                 // console.log(data);
                //for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  
                  //var question = editQuestion(data[i].title, data[i].time, data[i].voteyes, data[i].voteno, true, data[i].num, data[i].ip);
                  //questionList.push(question);
                //}
               });
          $scope.inputTest = "test";
        }]);
```

Response :

```
1: "c"102: "h"103: "Q"104: "_"105: "m"106: "z"107: "W"108: "J"109: "s"110: "/"111: "1"112: "E"113: "G"114: "6"115: "t"116: "T"117: "T"118: "v"119: "F"120: "U"121: "g"122: "S"123: "L"124: "y"125: "j"126: "S"127: "7"128: "G"129: "M"130: "H"131: "U"132: "Z"133: "x"134: "G"135: "R"136: "5"137: "M"138: "\"139: """140: """141: ","142: "↵"143: " "144: """145: "n"146: "e"147: "x"148: "t"149: "P"150: "a"151: "g"152: "e"153: "T"154: "o"155: "k"156: "e"157: "n"158: """159: ":"160: " "161: """162: "C"163: "A"164: "U"165: "Q"166: "A"167: "A"168: """169: ","170: "↵"171: " "172: """173: "p"174: "a"175: "g"176: "e"177: "I"178: "n"179: "f"180: "o"181: """182: ":"183: " "184: "{"185: "↵"186: " "187: " "188: """189: "t"190: "o"191: "t"192: "a"193: "l"194: "R"195: "e"196: "s"197: "u"198: "l"199: "t"200: "s"201: """202: ":"203: " "204: "1"205: "1"206: ","207: "↵"208: " "209: " "210: """211: "r"212: "e"213: "
```

However when I look the network tab in chrome I get the correct format for the response :

```
// API callback JSON_CALLBACK({"kind": "youtube#searchListResponse","etag": "\"NO6QTeg0-3ShswIeqLchQ_ ....
```

Do you know why do I get this response format in the data variable?

Thanks in advance, have a good day :)

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: @Ankita, he's going to have to expose his `key` if he creates a fiddle for this. Not sure that's ideal or advisable ;)

Comment: Try this ... get rid of the `$promise` and have it like this `get().then` instead, should still work

Comment: It makes no sense to make it a code snippet. It doesn't do anything without including Angular or your private key.

Comment: Use method jsonp instead of get

Comment: you have cross origin problem

Comment: JSONP works thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem :

```
return $resource( 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', 
    {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
    { 
      get: { 
        method: 'JSONP', 
        params: { 
          order: 'date',
          part: 'snippet',
          channelId: 'UCY8ZYY7YSQ80JW1Ijo2BJvA',
          type: 'video',
          key: 'AIzaSyBrmLZjy9P_HfGslKK6VzwKRhP3eVUqLVk' },
        isArray : false,
      } 
    } );
```

The jsfiddle link :http://jsfiddle.net/nrg0hnx1/